# Как получить данные из формы express js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post, express

Не могу получить данные из формы.

Форма.

```html
<form action="/addNewQuest" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите название квеста" class="re_quest_text_area">
  <input type="textarea" name="description" placeholder="Введите название квеста" class="re_quest_description_area">
  <input type="text" name="tasks" placeholder="Введите задания для квеста через символ '' | '' " class="re_quest_tasks_area">
  <input type="text" name="answers" placeholder="Введите ответы на задания через символ '' | '' " class="re_quest_answers_area">
  <input type="file" name="map" accept="image/svg+xml" class="re_quest_svg">
  <input type="submit" value="Создать">
</form>
```

Сервер.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db = require('db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages/index');
  console.log(req.url);
});

app.get('/*(.html)', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages' + req.url.slice(0, -5) + '.ejs');
  console.log('pages' + req.url.slice(0, -5) + '.ejs');
});

app.post('/addNewQuest', function(req, res, ) {
  console.log(req.body, req.body.name); // {}, undefined
  console.log("POST polychen");
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Приложение запущено! Смотрите на http://localhost:8080');
```

Испробовал уже много разных вариантов, которые нашел в гугле, но не один не помог.

Comment: Что получаете? Что хотите получить?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/multer пробовали?

Comment: Форма из полей для текста и svg. Пока пытаюсь получить текст из инпутов. multer еще не пробовал, сейчас проверю.

Comment: @Suvitruf Большое спасибо, все работает. Как понимаю это из-за атрибута encrypt?

Comment: Не могу сказать, я на express только REST сервисы делаю, там у меня всегда json'ы гуляют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставлю как ответ, если кто-то ещё с таким столкнётся.

Для express есть модуль [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer):

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer()

app.post('/profile', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.body будет содержать текстовые поля
})
```